# Reindex programmatically in magento

Tags: magento2, reindex, product-reindexing

I am new to magento. i have to indexer:reindex pragmatically and i looking for this solution. i found few source but there is no guide how and where i can use this code.
https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-perform-reindexing-programmatically-in-magento-2/
https://meetanshi.com/blog/reindexing-programmatically-in-magento-2/?unapproved=5643&moderation-hash=53af9c0f74f9daeedd1027c1a93eaf15#comment-5643

can someone please guide me through?

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/reindexing-programmatically-in-magento-2/?unapproved=5643&moderation-hash=53af9c0f74f9daeedd1027c1a93eaf15#comment-5643 this asking first you create the your custom module and  Create `Data.php` file this path `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Helper`.

Comment: I have pasted the code in this folder but what's next?

Comment: next run all commands ...